# Clustering in Ejabberd in 2 linux OS

Tags: ejabberd

I am currently trying to cluster ejabberd using 2 ubuntu instances but I am facing some problems. I have 2 instances inside oracle Virtual Box .My current ejabberd.yml file for both instances have the following host:-

```
hosts:
  - "xyz-VirtualBox"
```

For node1 I modify the ejabberdctl.cfg and change the ejabberd name like the following for example

```
ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@1.1.1.1
INET_DIST_INTERFACE=1.1.1.1
```

where 1.1.1.1 is the ip of my ubuntu machine 1 instance .I make sure that I have the same .erlang.cookie in 2nd ubuntu machine and done the same changes of NODE and INTERFACE for machine2 . I start my first instance by using

ejabberdctl start
and it works fine because I can access the webadmin console. I start my ejabberd on second instance using using

```
ejabberdctl start
```

and it runs fine when I try to add the cluster to instance using the following command

```
ejabberdctl --no-timeout join_cluster ejabberd@1.1.1.1
Error: {no_ping,'ejabberd@1.1.1.1'}
```

note - cmd> hostname --fqdn (machine 1 output - xyz-VirtualBox)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have this in machine 1:

```
ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@1.1.1.1
```

and something like this in machine 2:

```
ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@1.1.1.2
```

Can machine 2 connect to machine 1. I mean, In machine 2, does this work?

```
ping 1.1.1.1
```

If that pings correctly, then you can test with step 4 of that tutorial, to see if that works: https://ejabberd.im/interconnect-erl-nodes/index.html

Comment: Yes i have added all the details in /etc/hosts file. BTW now the clustering is working , the main issue was the Hostname used in ejabberd.yml (This should be user server name) and in all other places it should be your machine Hostname.